# "Submission cannot be done" displayed while submitting a form

Tags: formsflow.ai, formsflow

Created a form as a designer role. Then tried to submit the same form. But getting the below error
[image]

Comment: Can you check if you had linked the FORMIO IDS correctly in environment variables as mentioned in docs?

https://github.com/AOT-Technologies/forms-flow-ai-dev/blob/develop/forms-flow-forms/README.md#formsflow-forms-userrole-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the environment variables are not being mapped correctly as mentioned in the docs. You can check this [link](https://github.com/AOT-Technologies/forms-flow-ai/tree/master/forms-flow-forms#formsflow-forms-userrole-api) to set the correct values for environment variables (DESIGNER_ROLE_ID, ANONYMOUS_ID, CLIENT_ROLE_ID, REVIEWER_ROLE_ID, USER_RESOURCE_ID) either using postman or curl method. This will ensure the form submission works correctly.

In formsflow.ai we are using [formio](https://github.com/formio/formio) to create and manage forms. The environment variables which are missing are necessary for forms to be submitted correctly. Also ensure you have correctly done the [forms-flow-forms setup](https://github.com/AOT-Technologies/forms-flow-ai/tree/master/deployment/docker#forms-flow-forms-setup) and then proceeded to forms-flow-web setup.